# How to treat a byte[] as Int16[]?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, c#-4.0, arrays

I am receiving some raw data from audio input via `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy()` and this is stored in a byte[]. The actual data in that byte[] I know to be of type Int16. I would like to treat this byte[] as if it was an array of type Int16 and loop over its elements, process it and at the end of this I would like to pass this altered array as byte[] into another function.

For those who wonder what I'm trying to do: I would like to try adding an echo effect to the incoming sound (from mic) by simply adding up the wave data from previous buffer with the wave data from the current buffer, mixing it in at a lower volume.

EDIT: the byte[] array may be storing a int16 number 258 as a pair of bytes [1][2]

```
0000 0001 0000 0010
```

Comment: I think you want to combine every two bytes in a single Int16, right?

Comment: well, I know the individual pairs of bytes in that byte[] sitting next to each other do form a Int16.

Comment: Right, but it isn't / wasn't clear whether you want [1, 1] to result in [1, 1] or [257].

Comment: the actual number 258 would be found in that byte[] as successive two bytes [1][2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, as far as I'm aware.

I suggest you use `Buffer.BlockCopy` to copy the data into a `short[]`, work on it, and then copy it back. Of course, that assumes that the bytes are arranged in an appropriate endianness... but it's likely that they will be.

Alternatively... use the [overload of `Marshal.Copy` which accepts a `short[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146634.aspx) to copy the data into to start with.

Comment: i was just looking at the marshal.copy overload as you mentioned... (I will try your suggestions and take a deeper look into this once I get home from work)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BitConverter` to treat the bytes as Int16 elements using `BitConverter.ToInt16`. You can also use `Buffer.BlockCopy` to copy the array of bytes to an array of Int16s. The first is more memory efficient and the second is more speed efficient.